# Error in write function. Output file is empty despite successful compilation

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I am trying the write function in Fortran. The code is getting compiled and runs without any error but the output file is empty.

I'm using the Silverfrost Plato IDE. The file format is .f95.

```
program write
implicit none
open(12,file='myoutput.txt')
write(12,*) 'abcd'
print *, 'finished'
end program write
```

The expected output is that it writes 'abcd' in a text file and saves it in the same location as the executable but the text file is empty.

Comment: I assume you seen the 'finished', What happens with an explicit `close(12)? (should not be necessary). I would not name my program write like the write statement but that should not be the problem either.

Comment: The close(12) actually helped. Thanks mate!